# Unable to install ubuntu desktop

Tags: installation, 10.10

I am not able to install ubuntu. I am getting the following error,

```
Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason a1 on CPU 0.
You have some hardware problem, likely on the PCI bus.
Dazed and confused, but trying to continue.
```

How to solve this issue?

### Note:

I am installing ubuntu 10.10. I have changed the ubuntu iso image and version also, but still i am facing the same issue.

**System Specification:**

Dell Optiplex - 380

Ram       : 1 GB
Processor : Dual Core @ 3.20 GHz
Harddisk  : 250 GB

I am not seeing any option to disable SMP in Bios.

Comment: Please provide information about the version that you are trying to install and preferably add that to the tags as well.

Comment: Ever figure this out? It's just been allocated to me during [Clean-Up](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2863/its-time-for-clean-up-week).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is on older hardware with broken SMP, or on newer hardware that the kernel in the installer doesn't quite work with.  In the case of the SMP, try to change the SMP version in BIOS, or disabling it outright.

I have had problems with some motherboards on older kernels.  You can try to boot with the kernel flag noacpi and/or noapic.

If you provide us with information about the hardware you're trying to install on, it may give us better clues as to what's going on.

Comment: Also say me how to boot with kernel flag ?

Comment: I have upgraded the bios version and the upgradation was successful. But still i am facing the same problem. What may be the issue?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation, as well as description of the options I listed above and a few others at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: I also found a few others with server hardware giving them problems.  They recommend disabling C-States in the BIOS, which may be called something else, but is related to power-saving modes of the CPU itself.  You can read more about this and other possible kernel boot options at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=548198

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways. Will it be some hardware issue? I have tried changing my harddrive and ram but stil the problem persists. How to debug the issue?

Comment: If after all of this the problem persists, I think it's a motherboard issue.  If your machine is new enough and still under warranty, you should contact them.  I doubt a warranty replacement would solve the problem, but it's worth a try.  Otherwise, if it still fails with a new machine, I would demand that they give you credit to exchange for a different model.  This is a very rare condition, so don't get discouraged!  Ubuntu is great.